# Extending Phonegap's boilerplate index.js

Tags: javascript, cordova

If you create an app with Phonegap 3.6 CLI, you get the following index.js sample code:

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Although I know the basics of JavaScript, I'm not familiar with the code style used, so I was wandering if someone would explain the different sections and the `onDeviceReady: function()` syntax which in the Phonegap documentation is shown differently:

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

I was also wondering where exactly would be the best place to extend the sample code in order to build my own app. Do I just replace the `Update DOM on a Received Event` section, or do I rather include my own .js file with my JavaScript custom code?

Comment: I would be very interested to also have some explanation about this file. Did you find an interesting source of information on the web ?

Comment: Haven't looked into it any further, but recently discovered the Ionic framework as well as some interesting integrations with WordPress that make building a native app even more easy.